# Is $mc^2 = - (h^2/2m) d^2\psi/dx^2$ for a free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

I'm considering a one dimensional case and a time independent particle subjected to no potential. The main question is, if the particle has kinetic energy, where does that come from? Even if $mc^2$ is the manifestation of energy, maybe an object has to lose that mass so that mass gets converted to energy. Correct me if I am wrong (I have a rough idea about General Relativity)

Comment: I have downvoted this because as far as I can tell your confusion stems way before you get anywhere near quantum mechanics, back in a purely classical context. Please ask the non-quantum version of your question instead.

Comment: A time inpendent free wave function describes zero energy. It is constant throughout Minkowski space, so zero.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you are thinking something like

> The quantum mechanical energy from the TISE is 
>   $$ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(x) = E \;,$$
>   and in relativity we have 
>   $$ E = mc^2 $$
>   so I can just equate them using the $E$s, and because the particle is free set $V(x) = 0$.

Right?

Well, context is important here. In both cases, things have been left out to focus attention on the "important stuff".

- Schroedinger's equation is classical and neglects mass energy (because classically mass is never converted to other forms of energy, so why both carrying it around.)
- The reltativistic equation is considering a free particle (and depending on your interpretation of the symbol $m$ a motionless one at that; worse, if $m$ is the so-called "relativistic mass" it is different from the $m$ in the TISE which is a classical mass).<sup>1</sup>

So the two $E$s (and possibly also the two $m$s) are different things, and you can't combine them without paying attention to that.

How to do that is the subject of relativistic quantum mechanics.

---

<sup>1</sup> Your life will be easier here if you use $m$ as the invariant mass, and treat relativity in terms the don't have Lorentz factors in them. That is starting with the energy of a free particle given by $$E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2 \;.$$ At that point getting to the Klein-Gordon equation is pretty easy. And you *certainly* don't need any added complexity on the climb up to the Dirac equation.

Answer (score 0):

KE is the energy a body possesses by virtue of its inertia, and depends upon the reference frame in which it is measured. In the rest frame of the body it possesses no KE. So when you say 'if a particle has KE where does that come from?' what you mean is 'if a particle is moving where does the motion come from?' The answer could be anything, and depends upon the history of the particle.